# R extract function gives a weird error about the regex

Tags: r, dplyr, split, extract, tidyr

I have an excel file with one column. This column has a number and a state corresponding to this number.

| State |
| --- |
| 01 Alabama |
| 02 Alaska |

and so on. I would like to extract this column into two columns, one containing the number the other containing the state name. I tried to use extract() from tidyr:

```
df <- read_xlsx("States.xlsx")
df %>% tidyr::extract(States,c("A","B"),sep="(\\d\\d) ([a-zA-Z]+)")
```

But, it spits the error:

```
Error: `regex` should define 2 groups;  found.
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `sep`

Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?extract`

> regex - a regular expression used to extract the desired values. There should be one group (defined by ()) for each element of into.

There is no argument by the name `sep` in `extract`.  It is `regex`.  The `sep` is an argument in `separate` and not in `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  tidyr::extract(States,c("A","B"),regex="(\\d\\d) ([a-zA-Z]+)")
```